# Jupyter-notebook asks for token every time I move pages

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm running a remote jupyter notebook

ssh -L localhost:MYPORT:localhost:jupyterport me@theotherplace
jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=jupyterport

I get what you'd expect: an address localhost:jupyterporttoken=STUFF

but navigation from the root dir says forbidden.

If I click on the provided link, I get into the notebook.  However, from this point on, if I click a link in the page, it says forbidden.  I've set a password on the notebook and then I'm required to type that in every time I navigate.  For the record, I'm running on Windows 11 using Edge Chrome.  When I did this from a Linux machine, no issue at all.